# PHP code displaying in browser after clicking live preview in Brackets

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

I have xammp up an running with Apache and mysql on. I have attached an image of my settings. [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVn7o.png)  I notice my PHP Debugger says Server Listening on port 9000. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: what happens if you just go to the localhost?

Comment: try opening http://localhost/Learn/index.php and see what is shown

Comment: @nerdyist My project is inside of a folder called learn, if I just set it to localhost it won't be able to locate my php files, I haven't tried it but I am sure thats what would happen

Comment: @Oliver sorry that was unclear. Not using brackets what if you go to the localhost:80/Learn... You should not need index.php as that is the default file that is accesses...

Comment: @PRYM What in the world.... It works!!!! But why? Why not through my Brackets program?

Comment: Bracket shows a popup in the screenshot, Live preview base url, have you clicked on done ?

Comment: So take that url and place it in the brakets dialogue. It looks like you do not have a capital L in Learn

Comment: Strange after I entered the link manually, my live preview is now working slighty. The live preview shows the result however it doesn't maintain the connection stating "it was canceled because it navigated to a page not in the projects..."  which I don;t understand because the file is in the project. I've done a short video recording of what happens https://osaintilien55-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/NzcwMTgzXzM0ODk2MjA

Answer (score -1):

you are supposed to copy php files in htdocs folder inside xampp installation folder

then open localhost/filename path in browser to open it

Comment: Forgot to show the directory but yeah the files are located there...E:\program\xampp\htdocs\Learn

Comment: type localhost/Learn/index.php in your browser